# Why can't I launch the navigation stack from the same launch file as the simulation and the mapper?

Tags: ros, ros-humble, ros2-launch

I have this seemingly simple launch file:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="launch_nav" default="false" />

  <include
      file="$(find-pkg-share turtlebot3_gazebo)/launch/turtlebot3_world.launch.py"
      unless="$(var launch_nav)"
      />

  <include
      file="$(find-pkg-share rtabmap_demos)/launch/turtlebot3_scan.launch.py"
      unless="$(var launch_nav)"
      />

  <include
      file="$(find-pkg-share nav2_bringup)/launch/navigation_launch.py"
      if="$(var launch_nav)"
      >
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
  </include>

</launch>
```

For some reason I can't launch all of these at the same time. If I don't use the conditionals, the launch file will crash with an error (some windows will still open though, e.g., gzclient and rtabmap_viz):

```
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

If I include the conditionals and run them in separate shells, like this, it works as expected:

```
$ ros2 launch test.launch.xml launch_nav:=false
```

and

```
$ ros2 launch test.launch.xml launch_nav:=true
```

What is going on? Can anyone reproduce this? Am I doing something wrong?

On another computer with Ubuntu 20.04 running foxy, this doesn't happen and it launches as expected.